# real time styling as i write inside a editable div with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, styles

I've **[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gamito/KWmrf/4/)** showing what I want to do.
Basically, i want to style my text when certain words are typed. This styles will inform the user that the syntax they're using to build the query is right.

```
$(function () {
$('.textarea').focus();
$('.textarea').keyup(function () {
    var a = $(this).text().split(" ").join("</span> <span>");
    a = "<span>" + a + "</span>";
    $('.result').html(a);

    $('.result').find(":contains('where')").addClass('where marker').next().addClass('where value');
    $('.result').find(":contains('since')").addClass('since marker').next().addClass('since value');
});
});


// try writing 'hero where London since 2008' in textarea
```

It is working in another div (result) but what I really want is that styled output to be in the same div that I write (textarea),

Can anyone take a look at it and help?
Thanks

Comment: instead of doing the highlighting stuff yourself you could think of using [codemirror](http://codemirror.net/) with your own language rule.

Comment: @t.niese thanks. I'll follow that link

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your fiddle, I set it to use jQuery 1.9 and put in your code and a bit of HTML/CSS and it seems to be doing what you want.

HTML:

```
<div class="textarea" contenteditable></div>
<div class="result"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.textarea {
    min-height: 20px;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
.marker {
    color: red;
}

.value {
    color: blue;
}
```

JS:

```
$('.textarea').keyup(function () {
    var a = $(this).text().split(" ").join("</span> <span>");
    a = "<span>" + a + "</span>";
    $('.result').html(a);

    $('.result').find(":contains('where')").addClass('where marker').next().addClass('where value');
    $('.result').find(":contains('since')").addClass('since marker').next().addClass('since value');
});
```

Result:
[image: Fiddle Results]

Is this what you want to happen, or should something be different?

Comment: i'm sorry but it seems that my fiddle link was incorrect and you ended up giving me code I already have. Thanks anyway and i'm sorry for this mess.

What I want is the end result to show in .textarea as I type.
The .result div is there just for demonstrating how it should work.
http://jsfiddle.net/gamito/KWmrf/4/

Thanks
Jorge